# How can I get my Chrome icon back?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

Somehow the Google Chrome entry in the applications menu disappeared in Ubuntu.

Is there a simple way of getting it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To edit the menu, right click on it and go to 'Edit Menus'. Find Chrome, and double click to bring up the properties window. Press its picture to select a new icon. Mine was in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps`, and yours might be around there somewhere. if not, you can always [download a new icon yourself.](http://www.google.com/images?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=chrome%20logo&oe=utf-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi#q=chrome+logo&um=1&hl=en&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&tbs=isch:1,isz:i&source=lnt&ei=mv_kS8vKKImAMr3r4KsM&sa=X&oi=tool&resnum=3&ct=tlink)

Answer (score 5):

1- Create a desktop file (e.g. chrome.desktop) on your Desktop and insert the following content into that file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome
Name=Google Chrome
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/google-chrome.png
```

2- Make it executable by running this command:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/chrome.desktop
```

3- Add it to the launcher:

```
cp ~/Desktop/chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Comment: This solution led me to idea that I accidentally could corrupt *~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop* file when I was fixing annoying login keyring messages. And this is exactly what happened. Just had to fix the `Icon=` line.